# Logo acompanhando scroll da página(problema)

Tags: jquery, css

fiz um jquery para adicionar um fixed no logo da pagina dependendo da quantidade de rolagens scroll, porém está muito feito, quando ela passa a quantidade de scroll que o logo fica fixed o logo da um "pulinho" para o meio da página... Bom a página é politicadascidades.com.br observem o logo quando você rola a página uma certa quantidade.

Bom meu código jquery está assim

```
        $(function(){   
        var nav = $('#titulo');   
        $(window).scroll(function () { 
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100   ) { 
                nav.addClass("titulo-fixo"); 
            } else { 
                nav.removeClass("titulo-fixo"); 
            } 
        });  
    });
```

e o css que ele vai adicionar é

```
   .titulo-fixo{

   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   z-index:99;

  }
```

Já tentei diminuir ou aumentar a rolagem mas o "pulinho" é inevitável

Comment: pq vc nao deixa ele fixed de uma vez?

Comment: Sim fiz isso @andrepaulo mas ai ele comeu a imagem debaixo

Comment: na imagem de baixo voce tem que dar o respiro, ex. `margin-top: 100px;`

Comment: `#mobileFachada{ margin-top: 158px;}`

Comment: Consegui resolver muito Obrigado a todos fiz quase igual o andrepaulo falou deixei fixed de inicio logo e adicionei um margin-top de 2%

Comment: responde a pergunta, com o código usado e aceita a resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um exemplo de cabeçalho fixo no topo que acompanha o `scroll`, como o amigo andrepaulo comentou, existem diversas maneiras tanto com jquery quanto com css de fazer uma "animação" para fixar o cabeçalho no topo quando por exemplo o `.scrollTop() > 100`, caso queira usar, de uma olhada em [jQuery animate](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp) / [CSS transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

```js
$(function() {
  var nav = $('#titulo');
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      //nav.addClass("titulo-fixo");
    } else {
      //nav.removeClass("titulo-fixo");
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
#titulo {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  position:fixed;
  opacity:0.5;
  top:0;
  z-index:99;
}

body{
height:2000px;
}

.conteudo{
margin-top:60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="titulo">
  Cabeçalho
</div>
<div class="conteudo">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque fringilla eros ac dignissim auctor. In elit massa, congue vitae ipsum sit amet, ultrices eleifend erat. Nunc sit amet elementum enim, et vehicula magna. Nulla facilisi. Etiam fermentum magna in faucibus rutrum. Cras condimentum bibendum tortor id convallis. Donec a sapien vitae ligula porta euismod. Nulla sed risus sed augue lobortis vehicula vitae sit amet risus.

Aliquam elit mi, imperdiet at commodo quis, cursus et massa. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc fringilla pretium magna scelerisque facilisis. Etiam vehicula lectus a varius tincidunt. Curabitur sagittis nibh erat, id finibus neque aliquam ac. Curabitur ornare diam vel pellentesque facilisis. Suspendisse odio diam, consectetur ac maximus finibus, eleifend id nibh. Sed at ante quis turpis dapibus iaculis nec vitae nisl. Vivamus dictum metus in aliquam tincidunt. Praesent et arcu semper, venenatis nisi sit amet, suscipit arcu.

Suspendisse nibh mauris, mollis vitae ornare eget, tristique eu ligula. Vivamus porttitor malesuada lacus. Sed elit libero, bibendum nec aliquam vitae, ullamcorper sit amet justo. Donec egestas sem et efficitur tempus. Praesent luctus odio eu fermentum euismod. Morbi dictum et justo nec bibendum. Integer aliquam lacinia erat, eu consequat nulla pellentesque quis. Cras auctor, elit quis finibus consectetur, neque elit elementum nunc, eget consequat urna leo sit amet est. Nulla lobortis porta erat vestibulum iaculis.

Phasellus mollis congue dolor sed ultrices. Cras euismod orci tempus lacinia sodales. Nunc id nisl scelerisque, sagittis libero sit amet, porta eros. Quisque dapibus magna purus, id hendrerit risus ornare in. Vivamus aliquet justo vel sapien tincidunt dapibus. Curabitur posuere, mi eu pulvinar sollicitudin, nisl lectus porta est, cursus consectetur urna elit vitae sapien. Aliquam tellus dolor, tincidunt id tortor at, rutrum suscipit nulla.
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Amigo, aproveitando... esse logo fixo quando utilizado no navegador UCBrowser de celular ele oculpa a tela inteira, você sabe o por que?, no chrome de celular vai normal mas nele não vai

Comment: @AndersonHenrique Exatamente o porque de ficar ocupando a tela inteira não sei, mas presumo que seja alguma incompatibilidade com algum atributo do css, aqui tem uma discussão sobre o assunto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851085/css-responsive-design-in-mobile-is-not-working-on-uc-browser-and-opera-mini

Answer (score 0):

Bom oque eu basicamente fiz, retirei o jquery e coloquei fixed de primeira, depois só adicionei um margin-top na imagem abaixo.

```
#titulo {
width:100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 99;
}

#mobileFachada{
margin-top: 2%;
 }
```